# Использование паттерна 'Builder'

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Для чего нужен паттерн программирования `Builder`? Как написано в некоторых учебниках, он используется для того чтобы предотвратить создание **конструкторов** для сетера всех вариантов филдов.

Как альтернатива используется внутренний класс `Builder`, в котором дублируются все филды с дефолтными значениями. В классе есть сеттеры всех филдов.

В чем преимущества использования внутреннего класса `Builder`, ведь дефолтные значения для всех полей можно объявить в самом классе.

```
private Double emission = 0d;
...
```

Соответственно если нужный сеттер не вызван, будет использоваться дефолтное значение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Билдеры необходимы, когда у вас есть класс:

- содержащий много полей
- поля иммутабельны (final)
- не все поля обязательны

Делать конструкторы под все варианты или один конструктор, скажем с 10-ю параметрами, неудобно.

---

Еще бывает ситуация когда есть некий процесс, на протяжении которого нужно наполнить объект данными (при чем при разных условиях какие-то поля могут быть задействованы, а какие-то - нет), а после этого отдать его иммутабельную версию. В таком случае удобно протаскивать по ходу процесса builder, а когда все будет готово - завершить сборку.

Answer (score 4):

Паттерн `Builder` очень часто используется в тех случаях когда у конструируемого объекта множество полей. Он позволяет более информативнее и удобнее передавать значения, например:

```
class People {
    final String name;
    final String surname;
    final String city;
    final Sex sex;
    final int age;

    public People(String name, String surname, String city, Sex sex, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.city = city;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Конструктор получается довольно раздутым. При передаче параметров легко ошибиться и перепутать порядок, например, имени и фамилии. Так же, тут нельзя учесть, дефолтные значения.

С `Builder`'ом, код будет выглядеть более лаконичнее:

```
People man =  People
                    .builder()
                    .withName("Artem")
                    .withSurname("Konovalov")
                    .sex(MALE)
                    .age(25)
                    .liveIn("Saratov")
                    .build();
```

Comment: В таком возрасте такие ответы писать -- мое почтение :).

Comment: @andreycha ахаха, немного переборщил)

Comment: Лаконичнее он стать как раз не может (к каждому параметру теперь нужно указывать имя метода). Читабельнее - да.